# Axios me devuelve un HTML, Vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-8

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi vue para poder realizar una consulta a travez de mi controlador y cargar los datos de dicha consulta en los campos de mi formulario:

```
getUsuarioById(){
            
            this.fullscreenLoading=true;
            
            var url= 'administracion/usuario/getListarUsuarios'
            axios.get(url, {
                params: {
                    'nIdUsuario': this.fillEditarUsuario.nIdUsuario,
                }
            }).then(response=>{
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.fillEditarUsuario.cPrimerNombre    =   response.data[0].firstname;
                    this.fillEditarUsuario.cSegundoNombre   =   response.data[0].secondname;
                    this.fillEditarUsuario.cApellido        =   response.data[0].lastname;
                    this.fillEditarUsuario.cUsuario         =   response.data[0].username;
                    this.fillEditarUsuario.cCorreo          =   response.data[0].email;
                    this.fullscreenLoading = false;
            })
        },
```

esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('administracion/usuario/getListarUsuarios', [UserController::class, 'getListarUsuarios']);
Route::get('/{optional?}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->name('basepath')
  ->where('optional', '.*');
```

este es el controlador en el cual recibo los datos para hacer la consulta y donde controlo si esty recibiendo o no datos para realizar dicha consulta:

```
public function getListarUsuarios(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
        
        $nIdUsuario     = $request->nIdUsuario;
        $cNombre        = $request->cNombre;
        $cUsuario       = $request->cUsuario;
        $cCorreo        = $request->cCorreo;
        $cEstado        = $request->cEstado;

        $nIdUsuario =   ($nIdUsuario   ==  NULL) ? ($nIdUsuario   =  0) :   $nIdUsuario;
        $cNombre    =   ($cNombre   ==  NULL) ? ($cNombre   =   '') :   $cNombre;
        $cUsuario   =   ($cUsuario   ==  NULL) ? ($cUsuario   =   '') :   $cUsuario;
        $cCorreo    =   ($cCorreo   ==  NULL) ? ($cCorreo   =   '') :   $cCorreo;
        $cEstado    =   ($cEstado   ==  NULL) ? ($cEstado   =   '') :   $cEstado;

        $rpta       =   DB::select('call sp_Usuario_getListarUsuarios (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                                                                [
                                                                    $nIdUsuario,
                                                                    $cNombre,
                                                                    $cUsuario,
                                                                    $cCorreo,
                                                                    $cEstado,  
                                                                ]);
        return $rpta;
    }
```

el problema es que la consulta para llenar los campos del formulario no funciona:
explico como es el procediemiento:

primero desde mi index.vue hago una consulta para buscar el registro que quiero editar como lo muestra la siguiente imagen, en este caso tambien uso la misma funcion de controlador getListarUsuario para traer los registros de 1 o mas usuarios, luego presiono el boton de editar para llamar a mi edit.vue y hacer la carga en mi formulario de los datos, en este caso llamo de nuevo a getListarUsuario pero enviandole un id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta imagen muestra como el procedimiento para traer los usuarios desde el index.vue funciona correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo cuando llamo al procedimiento desde edit.vue no funciona, me devuelve este codigo HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Y si esa ruta la pasas por POSTMAN? que respuesta te da? o si puedes mostrar tu respuesta en console.log

Comment: me devuelve el HTML de la segunda imagen, pero solo sucede cuando hago la llamada con el edit.vue

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia en Laravel pero si en REST, y segun entiendo en tus rutas no estas mandando ningun json al frontend, la ruta se debe ver algo asi `[GET] getlListarUsuarios/{id_user}` en tu ruta estas mandandole un HTML `return view('app');`

Comment: Posiblemente porque este condicional `if(!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');` resulta verdadero, y te redirige a la /

Answer (score 0):

asegúrate de estar pasando los headers en el request que estás haciendo con axios:

```js
axios.get(url, {
  params: {
      'nIdUsuario': this.fillEditarUsuario.nIdUsuario,
  },
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json'
  }
}
```

Comment: acabo de hacer ese cambio y sigue sin funcionar